# Chrome driver doesn't load resources in a page

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to load a web page with Selenium 3 and chrome driver in a Docker container and I don't see the resources loading in there. Below is how the web page looks when I load it in the docker container. Chromedriver version here is 86

[image]

But when I load it from my local machine the web page loads fine with all the resources. Below is how the remote driver is initiated for execution in Docker.

Below is the list of ChromeOptions I use. (Casting here is because of multiple other browser options returned from this same method)

```
    options = new ChromeOptions();
    ((ChromeOptions) options).setBinary("/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome");
    ((ChromeOptions) options).setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    ((ChromeOptions) options).addArguments("--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    ((ChromeOptions) options).addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    options.setCapability("browserVersion", "general");
```

Then instantiating the driver like this.

```
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
    url,
    SeleniumHelper.getCapabilities("chrome",
        myGrid.getForwardProxy()));
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why aren't the resources loading? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I ran into this problem as well - did you have any luck in resolving it?

Comment: Nope unfortunately still facing it. Let me know if you find something please!